# How do I grab data between two indexes

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Have a code where it ranks users by its rate.

```
const rankings = await Rating.aggregate([{"$group": {_id:"$receiver", value: {$sum: "$rate"}}}]).sort({reputation: "desc"});
```

The output looks something like this

```
[
  { _id: 'bob', value: 3 },
  { _id: 'joe', value: 2 },
  { _id: 'billy', value: 2 },
  { _id: 'joseph', value: 2 },
  { _id: 'kim', value: 1 },
  { _id: 'jane', value: 0 }, ....
]
```

However since this is a long list >100, I am trying to create a page where it display only 10 users each. How do I accomplish this?

I know I can use slice(index1, index2), but if I use slice(), I'm scared that the execution time will be slow since its retrieving every data from db first then slicing them.

Is this something I should be worried about?, if yes is there a way to just grab data between index-1 to index-2 straight from the database?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `$skip` & `$limit` as a part of aggregation pipeline.

As an example following code will -

- match all records satisfying conditions specified in `filterMatchQuery` object
- skip number of records specified in `skip` variable
- and limit the number of records to the number specied in `limit` variable

  ```
   await Rating.aggregate([
       { $match: filterMatchQuery }
       { $skip: skip },
       { $limit: limit }
   ]);
  ```

I hope this helps.